# material cards in material radio button group for responsive design

Tags: css, angular, responsive-design, angular-material

Building an angular application with angular material. The user has option to pay by credit card or by bank account transfer klarna.
So, in a radio button group, with 2 radio button options, there are material cards for each of the radio buttons.
Now each of these have images which have different text sizes.
How do I get the material cards to have the same size in a responsive design.
I have tried with Bootstrap, Angular Flex Layout, good old CSS and failed miserably.

The thing is the material cards by themselves I am able to keep them as the same size as long as they aren't part of the radio button. So please help.
See the stackblitz for the Angular App here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nykksq?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.html

This is how I would want it to look like on all screen sizes:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vbu5n.png)

Comment: Do you have an example of you want it to look?

Comment: i have provided it in the stackblitz url

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using css flexbox and a media query. See:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-f1sjdd?file=src/app/app.component.css

Most importantly, one has to set the width of the material card and material card title.
So that the title has a word wrap we should use white-space: normal

That's it.